# VBS running a file on a .bat

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I am trying to run a .bat file as part of my VBScript with the parameter of another file.

I have tried:

```
    param1 = CurrentFolder & "\file.extension"
    command = "C:\folder name\compiler.bat"

    Set WScript = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WScript.run "cmd " & command & " " & param1
```

But nothing seems to work.

Im trying to achieve the same as if I dragged "file.extension" and dropped it onto "compiler.bat"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Choose a different name for your `Shell` object. `WScript` is a built-in, global object in WSH. For example:

   ```
   Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   ```
2. Try this for your `Run` statement:

   ```
   objShell.Run "cmd /c " & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & command & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & param1 & Chr(34) & Chr(34)
   ```

The `/c` will close the prompt when the command completes. The `Chr(34)`'s are used to put quotes around your command and your parameter, in case either contains spaces. Note that you also need quotes around the entire statement. For example:

```
cmd /c ""c:\folder name\compiler.bat" "a param with spaces""
```